# How to edit callto registry so it automatically dials a number in Windows Phone Dialer

Tags: tapi

I have an ISDN phone which supports TAPI/CTI and connects to my PC via serial port.
I can use Windows Dialer (dialer.exe) which is pre installed on Windows to tell the phone what number to call. It works perfectly and all I have to do is lift the reciever!

What I want to do is be able to use the callto: url which when clicked, automatically opens the application and begins dialling (like what Skype would do).
In the registry editor, I can edit the command from

```
"C:\PROGRA~2\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" "/callto:%l"
```

to

```
"C:\Windows\System32\dialer.exe" "/callto:%l"
```

Now when I click on a callto: url, the program opens but nothing happens.  I have tried a few different variations in the `"/callto:%l"` part but I am getting nowhere.

Is anybody good with registry edits? Can it be done with this program?

---

EDIT:
On second thoughts, if I cant achieve what I want above, can I set the callto link so that when clicked, it copies the link to the clipboard? Then manual paste can be done.

Comment: Is there really no insight at all about this?

Answer (score 1):

We use this dial.exe App that then uses the Dialer. You can find more info about it here: http://www.atrandom.iansharpe.com/phone-dial.php

I'll be taking the code and modifying it to support tel: links too as those work on Cell phones where as the CallTo: do not.